# Boostrap login popup model validation using jquery ajax and codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

MY Question: i click login button and open login popup model and i insert username and password and press submit button ,when if username and password is correct then redirect dashboard page ,and if username and password wrong then display error message in popup model. i used codeigniter fremework.please help me...

**controller:**

```
class Property extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
    }

    public function index() {
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        if ($username == 'admin' && $password == 'admin') {
            $user = array(
                'username' => $username,
                'password' => $password
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($user);
            echo json_encode($user);
        } else {
            $errormsg = "Invalid UserName and Password";
            echo json_encode($errormsg);
        }
    }

    public function property_owner_detail() {
        $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
        if (!empty($username)) {
            //$this->output->cache(3600);
            $this->load->model('event_model');
            $this->load->helper('date');
            $data = array(
                'page_title' => 'Property',
                'location_collection' => $this->event_model->list_all()
            );
            $this->load->view('property/index', $data);
        } else {
            redirect('/Site');
        }
    }

}
```

**View:**

```
<li><a href="#" style="color: red" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#property_owner_login">Login</a></li>


<div class="modal fade" id="property_owner_login" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title text-primary">Login</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?php echo form_open(); ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" required="">
                </div>
                <?php echo form_close(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" name="submit" id="property_owner_login" class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript file**

```
var property_owner_login = {
    mode: "Add",
    modal: $("#property_owner_login"),
    add: function () {
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Property",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {username: username, password: password},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                //console.log(data.username);

                if (obj.username == 'admin' && obj.password == 'admin') {
                    window.location.href = 'property/property_owner_detail';
                } else {

                }
            }
        });
    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#property_owner_login").click(function () {
        if (property_owner_login.mode == "Add") {
            property_owner_login.add();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what error are you facing

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript function, you need to check your response for an error message. You can format this how you like but for a login you do not want to give away too much info, like 'email not recognised', as I can keep plodding on until an email is recognised and then I am halfway there. So just have a generalised 'Email and Password do not match, please try again.' (Unless you have other mechanisms like an enforced and increasing delay of 2,4,8,16,32 etc. seconds between attempts or 3 trys and lockout etc).

You have to check your js response, and if it is, say, equal to ERROR or FAIL or FALSE or however you want to do it, then inset the generalised errormessage into a specific (albeit initially blank) error div within the modal, styled however you want it (using $('#myErroDiv') = html('Error message') or similar), just like in the way you are checking if they are admin or not.

You response to a login attempt can just be a simple TRUE or FALSE, with a redirect on TRUE and a general error message on FALSE. The user panel they go to on TRUE can then deal with showing admin pages or not depending on their role. There is no need to do it on the login attempt.

Hope that helps,

Paul.

Comment: How to validate input field

Comment: like username and password

Comment: $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length(6)|alphadash|callback_checkpassword'); where checkpassword is a private method that actually checks password and username match whatever your criteria are, usually that they match whatever is in your database.

Comment: I think I have answered your question, I am not going to do the work for you. It is very easy. You use your js to detect that your login attempt failed and you inject the standard error message into a pre-defined error message holder. All very straight forward JS, and certainly no more complex than anything you have already done. You are not going to learn anything if you just cut and paste whatever I suggest into your code. There is no single way of doing this, there are lots of implementations that would work. Find one that works the way you want it to.